# CouchDB view replication

Tags: view, nosql, couchdb, replication

Using CouchDB to create a hosted app for clients. I have a dev database I work from, as well as separate DBs for each client. Works well, problem is when I make a change on dev, I have to manually copy the view code into each separate DB. It's fine now that I have 2 clients. But my hope is to grow to 100 clients. One small change could take a very long time!

Am I missing something simple in regards to replicating ONLY the views?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I usually work.

1. I have my local dev db. create and update my design docs (containing the views).
2. Have a production deployment db that will be visible to all the clients. I usually use iriscouch. Keep no data in this db.
3. When setting up a client, make sure you setup one way replication from #2 to this client db.

So to deploy to all clients, I put my latest design docs on the master, then all the clients will then be updated. There are some caveats to this. You have to make sure when you deploy to the master db, that you respect the revisions, so the client dbs will know to update.

Here is a quote from the master, Jason Smith:

> ### The Good Way: Work with _rev
>
> I think your application has a concept of "upgrading" from one
> revision to another. There is staging or development code, and there
> is production code. Periodically you promote development code to
> production. That sounds like two Git branches and it also sounds like
> two doc ids. (Or two sets of doc ids.)
>
> You can test and refactor your code all day long, in the temporary doc
> (_design/dev). But in production (_design/pro), it's just like a long
> Git history. Every revision built from the one previous, to the
> beginning of time.
>
> If you want to promote _design/dev, the latest deploy is
> _rev=4-abcdef. So this will be the fifth revision deployed, right?
> Hey! Stop reading the "_rev" field! But yeah, probably.
>
> COPY /db/_design/dev
> Destination: _design/pro?rev=4-abcdef
>
> {"id":"_design/pro","rev":"5-12345whatever"}
>
> Notice that each deployed _design/pro builds from the other, so it
> will naturally float out to the slaves when they replicate.
>
> In real-life, you may have add a middle step, pushing design documents
> to production servers before actually publishing them. Once you push,
> how long will it take couch to build new views? The answer is,
> "Christ, who knows?"
>
> Therefore you have to copy _design/dev to _design/staging and then
> push that out into the wild. Then you have to query its views until
> you are satisfied that they are fresh and fast. (You can compare
> "update_seq" from /db vs. "update_seq" from /db/_design/ddoc/_info).
> And only then do you HTTP copy from _design/staging to _design/pro and
> let that propagate out.

[Source](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/couchdb-user/201108.mbox/%3CCAN-3CBKb2BvDf9DzRLw_G%3DhEKZKw_TVF-F19W9Hq%3DSbyDM5i%2Bw%40mail.gmail.com%3E)

Its not as confusing as it may sound. But to simplify the process, you can use [Reupholster](http://code.google.com/p/reupholster/wiki/ReleaseOhFourOne)
(I admit, I have written this tool). It is mainly for couchapps, but even if you are just promoting design docs, it might be worth you just using reupholster to deploy to your master db. Reupholster adds in some handy info to the design doc, like date/time svn or git info. That way when you look at a clients db you can tell which design doc they are on.

Good luck

Comment: +1. But I am only the master when I play Zendo. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zendo_%28game%29

Answer (score 1):

You can replicate just the design docs;

http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Replication#Named_Document_Replication